# Is there a theory which says that friendships determine the quality of your Philosophy?

Tags: theory

Is there a theory which says that friendships determine the quality of your Philosophy? How have your friendships shaped the quality of your philosophical life?

Comment: Hi Daniel, and welcome!  I see a legitimate question in the headline. But the body text makes me wonder if the question is just a snarky commentary on this community.  If it isn't, please rewrite the body text to elaborate on the main question, and eliminate the personal asides.

Comment: Thanks, done in quick step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed. Randall Collins, Professor Emeritus of sociology at U.Penn wrote an rather weighty tome on the topic, *[The Sociology of Philosophies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0674001877)*.  The basic idea is that great philosophers --and indeed, **great artists and intellectuals in every field, rarely occur in isolation**.  Close-knit creative communities --complete with friends, enemies, mentors, rivals, romantic entanglements, quarrels, collaboration, and outright intellectual theft --are typically from whence the towering figures of history emerge.

History may remember only one or two names from each group, but **the others are no less necessary** to the final result. No Descartes without Mersenne, no Mozart without Salieri, no Socrates without Gorgias, no Percy Shelley without Horace Smith, no Confucius without Lao Tzu, no Andre 3000 without Cee-Lo Green.

Comment: I just want you too know that I was wrong for acting like I'm James Dean in Rebel Without A Cause. I guess that's what strangers like do when they get frustrated. Bagels on me if I see you for setting me straight.